# Cisco ASA VPN DH Groups for AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, cisco, ipsec, isakmp

AWS provides a neat function in its VPC that exposes a VPN service. I've configured this, and confirmed that it functions.

Our customer is using a Cisco 5500 Series ASA appliance to connect to the AWS VPN service. The FAQ provided my AWS describes that the following Diffie-Hellman Groups are supported for Phase 1 and Phase 2:

> Q. Which Diffie-Hellman Groups do you support?
>
> We support the following Diffie-Hellman (DH) groups in Phase1 and Phase2.
>
> - Phase1 DH groups 2, 14-18, 22, 23, 24
> - Phase2 DH groups 1, 2, 5, 14-18, 22, 23, 24
>
> *Taken from http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/*

AWS provide an example configuration for the Cisco 5500 ASA appliance (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/Cisco_ASA.html). I can confirm that this does establish a tunnel(s).

However, the provided example config appears to be making use of DH Group 2 for both the Phase 1 and Phase 2 of the tunnel establishment, and is also using IKEv1, not IKEv2.

Cisco release notes for the 9.1.x firmware for the 5500 ASA appliance recommend that Group 1 and Group 2 be avoided, and in fact other sources suggest that group 5 should be avoided too (AWS VPC doesn't support Group 5 in Phase 1, so that's rather moot).

> When configuring for IKEv2, for security reasons you should use groups 21, 20, 19, 24, 14, and 5. We do not recommend Diffie Hellman Group1 or Group2. For example, use
>
> crypto ikev2 policy 10
>
> group 21 20 19 24 14 5
>
> *taken from Cisco ASA release notes for iOS version 9.1x*

AWS don't offer a Best Practice configuration, rather their example is a "starter for ten". I propose the following update to the AWS example configuration, but would like to have some confidence that this is going to achieve what I think it achieves before providing it to our customer.

Ln 48 - 54 changed to:

```
crypto ikev2 policy 10
  encryption aes256
  authentication pre-share
  group 24
  lifetime 28800
  hash sha256
exit
```

And Ln 117 changed to:

```
crypto map <amzn_vpn_map> 1 set pfs group24
```

There really seems to be a drought of validation of this configuration anywhere on the inter-space, so hopefully this message in a bottle drifts on to the shoreline of someone who's in the know!

Comment: Does it also need a change on Ln 119 to use IKEv2?
`crypto map <amzn_vpn_map> 1 set ikev2 transform-set transform-amzn`